# Split dataframe to two sub-dataframes based on string of column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Assuming dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(city = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("dc", 
"ld", "nj", "ny", "week1", "week2", "wt"), class = "factor"), 
    area = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 2L), price = c(7L, 4L, 3L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Out:

```
city   area price
week1   3   7       
  ny    2   4       
  dc    1   3       
week2   8   5       
  nj    3   1       
  wt    3   2       
  ld    2   2
```

In the dataframe above, `week1` row is sum of `ny` and `dc`, `week2` is sum of `nj, wt, ld`. How could I split it by `week2` to two dataframes and remove `week` rows?

The expected results will like this:

df1:

```
city   area price   
  ny    2   4       
  dc    1   3
```

df2:

```
city   area price   
  nj    3   1       
  wt    3   2       
  ld    2   2
```

My ideas to is to get the position of `week2`, then use:

```
df1 = df[1:index,]
df2 = df[(index +1) : nrow(df),]
```

Does that make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out position of 'week' rows and split the data based on that. From each list you can then remove the 1st row.

```
result <- lapply(split(df, cumsum(grepl('week', df$city))), function(x) x[-1, ])
```

Or shorter with `by` :

```
result <- by(df, cumsum(grepl('week', df$city)), function(x) x[-1, ])
```

---

Another way would be with `Map` :

```
inds <- grep('week', df$city)
result <- Map(function(x, y) df[x:y, ],inds + 1, c(inds[-1] - 1, nrow(df)))
result
#[[1]]
#  city area price
#2   ny    2     4
#3   dc    1     3

#[[2]]
#  city area price
#5   nj    3     1
#6   wt    3     2
#7   ld    2     2
```

---

You can assign names to the list `result` by :

```
names(result) <- paste0('df', seq_along(result))
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my stupid question, but how to assign names `df1` and `df2` for `result` or `by(df, cumsum(grepl('week', df$city)), function(x) x[-1, ])`? Since I need to count `length` or arrange based `area` for `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Added an update to name the list. Usually it is better to keep data in a list if you want to have them as separate dataframe you can do `list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)` after naming them.

Comment: `names(result)` returns `[1] "df1" "df2"`, but when I print `df1`, it can't find it.

Comment: Oops..sorry the code should be `list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)`